# Java 8 Streams difference between map and filter

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Result of both approach are same which is best practise to use. I am new bee to java 8. i am little bit confused on stream.map and stream.filter

```
List<String> alpha =
        Arrays.asList("a", "b", "csddddddddddd",
                "d", "ssdddddddddd", "sw", "we", "wew");

// Java 8
List<String> collect = alpha.stream()
        .map(String::toUpperCase)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> collect2 = alpha.stream()
        .map(s -> s.length())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> collect3 = collect2.stream()
        .filter(s -> s > 10)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> collect4 = collect2.stream()
        .map(s -> {
            Integer temp = 0;
            if (s > 10) {
                temp = s;
            }
            return temp;
        })
        .filter(s -> s > 10)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Result of both List are same :

```
[13, 12]
[13, 12]
```

what is best approach. and what is best approach in this regards.

Comment: In `collect4` you're performing an unnecessary `map` step and then using `filter` exactly the same as you used it in `collect3`. What is that supposed to demonstrate?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to filter the elements of a `Stream` by some condition (i.e. remove elements that don't satisfy the condition), use `filter`, not `map`.

The purpose of `map` is to convert an element of one type to an element of another type.

The only reason you get the same results in `collect3` and `collect4` is that after applying `map` in `collect4`, you apply a filter, which removes all the `0`s produced by `map`.

The entire `.map(s ->{ Integer temp = 0;if(s>10) {temp=s;} return  temp;})` call is redundant. That's a very unreadable and inefficient way to write code.